# How to get the missing pixel in my window?

Tags: javascript, html, viewport

I have some understanding trouble how clientX and clientY really work.
I want to get the coordinates of a mouse click in a window. And I really need them to be precisely.

My problem is now, that I get coordinates but when it comes to the right and bottom edge of my window the last pixel is just missing. I can't get my coordinates to have the full width or full height shown.

My window I'm working with has an inner dimension of 1920x916. And I need the x-coordinate to have a value from 0 to 1920. But it doesn't reach 1920. 1919 is the best I will get. Same problem with the height. Best is 915. Why?

```
        var winSize = document.getElementById("size");
        var mouseCoords = document.getElementById("coords");

        window.addEventListener("click", getCoords);

        function getCoords(e)
        {   
            var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
            var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
            winSize.innerHTML = windowWidth + ":" + windowHeight;

            var xPosition = e.clientX;
            var yPosition = e.clientY;
            mouseCoords.innerHTML = xPosition + ":" + yPosition;
        }
```

Here's my [little fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uLpf396c/)

Another small request: No JQuery please and I don't need to support IE or Safari.

Comment: for `1920x916` the pixel ranges are ... 0...1919 x 0...915 ... if you count the number of values, that's ... 1920 x 916 .... rather than counting 916 pixels ... imagine your screen was 1 x 1 ... the only pixel is 0,0 not 1,1

Comment: Oh... how could I forget this? I was just stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 1920 pixels numbered from 0, the max will be 1919.

If the coordinate was 1920, then you'd be looking at 1921st pixel.

0 is the first pixel,
1 is the second pixel
1919 is the one thousand nine hundred and twentieth pixel